# remove/hide pages from users backend

Tags: pages, users, user-roles, user-access, child-pages

I'm using this code in functions.php to hide/remove some pages from custom users backend and works well, but how can I reach to hide the subpages as well?

```
add_filter( 'parse_query' , 'exclude_pages_from_admin' );

function exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {

global $pagenow,$post_type;
 if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page' && current_user_can( 'custom_role' )) {
    $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array('1','2','3');
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by looping through the parent pages and fetching their respective children pages ids.

The resulting arrays can then be merged and used in the `'post__not_in'` variable.

```
add_filter( 'parse_query' , 'exclude_pages_from_admin' );

function exclude_pages_from_admin( $query ) {

    global $pagenow,$post_type;
    $pages   = array('1','2','3');
    foreach ( $pages as $parent_page ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_parent' => $parent_page,
            'fields' => 'ids',
        );
        $children = new WP_Query( $args );
        $pages = array_merge( $pages, $children );
    }
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page' && current_user_can('custom_role') ) {
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = $pages;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry I think I got the wrong end of the stick on this question! This method is for removing menu page.

I think a simpler method might be:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {

    global $user_ID;

    if ( current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); // Posts
        remove_menu_page('upload.php'); // Media
        remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
        remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
        remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' ); // Contact Form 7
        remove_menu_page('acf-options'); //acf options
    }

    if ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page('upload.php'); // Media
        remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
        remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
        remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' ); // Contact Form 7
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf' ); // ACF
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=cptui_manage_post_types' ); //CPT UI
    }

}
```

This is straight out of a current project that I am working on and works a treat!

Comment: Err, the OP doesn't want to remove menu but rather remove pages and sub pages from the Page list table on the backend